# is not a valid initializer for JSQMessagesBubbleImage error

Tags: ios, objective-c, messenger, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I connect the framework, like:

```
class MessagesViewController: JSQMessagesViewController {
    var outgoingBubleImage = JSQMessagesBubbleImage()
}
```

but it prints the next error:

```
is not a valid initializer for JSQMessagesBubbleImage. Use initWithMessageBubbleImage:highlightedImage: instead.'
```

Why this error appears?

Answer (score 0):

```
var outgoingBubbleImageData = JSQMessagesBubbleImage();
```

error [image: error]

Answer (score 0):

- (UIImage *)jsq_circularImage:(UIImage *)image withDiameter:(NSUInteger)diameter highlightedColor:(UIColor *)highlightedColor

// NSParameterAssert(image != nil);